# Can I change the order of cards stacked in each room?

Tags: mansions-of-madness

The first few times I played the game I've placed the cards in the rooms in the order that the Seed Cards reference tells me to, but I find that some cards at the bottom of each pile are supposed to be there to "unlock" access to the rest of the stacked cards within that room. Can I change the order each stack is placed on the board so it makes sense or do I need to follow the reference sheet which I find is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

**No**, you cannot change the order of the Seed cards.  However, do make sure that you are using the [latest errata](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/edge_minisite_sec.asp?eidm=136&esem=4).

If you have any specific concerns, please ask.  We can try to address this question without specifics.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I struggled with this as well. The order in the manual is the order in which you *lay the cards down*, so the card at the end of the list is the card that ends up on top.

So the exploration cards will always be under the obstacles/locks, and in the rare case where a room contains an obstacle and a lock, the lock will always be on top of the obstacle.

Also, equipment and clues are always on top of "nothing of interest" cards.